# Splunk Updating Event Status

Tags: splunk

I'm using Splunk REST API (C#)

I have an event_id, and I want to update the event status with HTTP POST request.

What I've tried is to send HTTP Post request with the following request body as json:

```
{'status': 5, 'urgency': 'high', 'newOwner': 'admin', 'output_mode': 'json', 'comment': 'This is a test of the REST endpoint', 'ruleUIDs': ['MYEVENTUID']}
```

And this is the response:

```
{"message": "No search ID was provided.", "success": false}
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change a splunk event that was already indexed? 
If so you can't, because splunk indexes are read only, and their data cannot be changed.

Comment: @barakai36, I have event_id, the event is with status (1), i want to change the event status to 2, i can to that, i have python script that do the update i just need to "convert" the python script to C# code

Comment: Please share the python script that does that.

Comment: @barkao36, You can see that here https://gist.github.com/LukeMurphey/29b61fc5837511efa531 or here http://blogs.splunk.com/2015/04/13/how-to-edit-notable-events-in-es-programatically/, I just try to "convert" this script to C#

Comment: Oh, so it's **notable** events in Splunk Enterprise Security, not a regular Splunk event.